# When setting java swing component visibility off in Matlab figure, a rectangle remains

Tags: java, matlab, swing, matlab-figure

I'm having trouble with a JProgressBar in a Matlab figure. My code is as follows:

```matlab
figure('color',[1 1 1]);
plot(gca, [0 1],[0 1])
pb = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JProgressBar');
javacomponent(pb, [0 0 300 30], gcf);
pb.setVisible(false)
```

When the progress bar's visibility is set to false, what remains is a gray rectangle that covers the plot. I tried disabling the progress bar or removing it, but couldn't do it with the object methods. Does anybody have any ideas on how to remove it when it's not visible?

Comment: This type of question will likely require that you work to isolate the source of the error and then create and post your [mre] in y our question.

Comment: Can I ask what it's missing? I thought it was a reprex. I ran the code on both windows and linux and observed the same behavior. First you create a figure and set the background white so the rectangle can be seen. Then plot something so you can see that the rectangle stays in front. Then get the java progress bar into the figure, and set it to invisible to see that it's still there. The issue is that I can't isolate the source of the error, so that's why I'm asking the question - seems a bit of a catch-22 that I have to isolate the source of the error...

Comment: Although I did try checking as much as I could - the figure properties, the java methods, etc.

Comment: ... but neither can we as we do not have code that we can compile, run or test, shoot, we don't even have code that is a viable compilable class or that has a main method starting point, and this suggests that you may benefit from doing more debugging, by paring down your code to the absolute smallest that compiles, runs and that shows the issue -- but the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) already tells you all this, hoping you've read it

Comment: If you've never created a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before, it does require a bit of work since the code has to be small enough to post here in your question in its entirety and must reproduce the problem, but often the effort is well spent.

Comment: Sorry, the way i use Matlab, the only thing necessary to run my code is that one have the Matlab software. If you don't have it, I wouldn't be able to provide that, so I guess I expected people who had matlab to maybe know about this issue. Unfortunately debugging doesn't seem to work with java objects/methods within Matlab - you can't step in to these methods

Comment: Which is exactly why it is best to avoid static fields (which make debugging and mocking much more difficult)  why we *should* create classes that have a single purpose, classes well separate the view from the model, and classes that allows independent testing and debugging of all classes, model and view. This way, the Matlab code can be debugged separately from the Swing code, allowing for easier bug isolation and fixing.

Comment: Do you speak from experience with matlab? I guess you're recommending I make my own class for progress bars? But java's already exists and seems pretty nice and is easy to draw in. And i figure there's a fix for this out there somewhere. Matlab usually has good debugging for other code, not sure why it doesn't work with imported java

Comment: No, not MatLab per se, but I have done a ***lot*** of Swing coding, including creating large *complex* programs that interface Swing GUI's with all sorts of other libraries, so I have a lot of debugging experience with the Swing library, and if I've learned one thing, it is to strive to separate model from view. Without this, the headaches multiply as the code complexity grows. And no, I would not recommend your own code for progress bar, but rather that (again) you separate the model (the thing you're monitoring) from the display of it

Comment: For a short time, I was coding with GNU Octave, but that was quite a bit ago

Comment: I mean, I'll think about that, but my primary work is done in Matlab so guess I don't see how the model can be separated any further from the display. The model would be whatever I'm plotting, and then the display includes the progress bar, but the progress bar is not part of the model. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple of possible fixes in case anybody encounters the same issue:

1. For the example I provided, the progressbar can be found in the figure's children property, and it can be deleted by, once it has been found, using `delete(fig.Children(1))` or whatever the index of the progressbar is. It seems that despite the order of adding to the figure, the JavaWrapper object is always the first child, so maybe this is why it's prominent even when invisible.
2. If using this with a UIFigure or other UI components, the order of components depends on the order of component creation and the order can be modified afterwards. One can use `uistack(uicomp, 'top')` to move components to the front (but not to move the progress bar to the back; matlab says the 'Parent' of the progress bar is not accessible)